# Composer autoloading vendor classes

Tags: php, json, composer-php, autoload

I have 2 packages on Packagist.

https://packagist.org/packages/erayalakese/envato-market-api (A)
https://packagist.org/packages/erayalakese/envato-update-checker (B)

B requires A.

Now I'm using B package on my projects. But I'm getting **Class 'erayalakese\Envato_Update_Checker' (package B) not found** error.

This is my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "",
    "description": "",
    "require": {
        "erayalakese/envato-update-checker": "^1.3"
    },
    "authors": ...
}
```

And my project file:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php');
new erayalakese\Envato_Update_Checker(...);
```

When I add this to my composer.json as temporary solution, it's working :

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["vendor/"]
}
```

But I'm not sure I really need to add **vendor** folder to **autoload** . I was expecting it will autoload my vendors automatically.

Can you tell me what's I'm missing?

Comment: It won't work that way, you have to require and init the class before call in methods. or you can use PSR-4 and reference to classes with namespace. [Composer classmap autoload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619063/composer-classmap-autoload-does-not-load-new-files-in-folder).

Comment: I'm using classmap as a temporary solution. And when i use classmap it's working without requiring classes one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the `composer.json` of both packages.

Both packages need to define a `autoload` section.

Referencing: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap

---

**erayalakese/envato-market-api**

https://github.com/erayalakese/envato-market-api/blob/master/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "erayalakese/envato-market-api",
    "description": "Envato Market API to verify and download Envato purchases",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Eray Alakese",
            "email": "erayalakese@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {},
    "license": "GPL v2",
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["Envato_Market_API.php"]
    }
}
```

Now this package has a autoload classmap definition, which consists of one PHP file. When you `composer install`, the autoload definition of the package will be added to the Composer Autoloader.

Same game for the other package:

**erayalakese/envato-update-checker**
https://github.com/erayalakese/envato-update-checker/blob/master/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "erayalakese/envato-update-checker",
    "description": "Checks Envato WordPress plugins' updates and download its if any update available",
    "require": {
        "erayalakese/envato-market-api": "^1.0"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Eray Alakese",
            "email": "erayalakese@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "license": "GPL v2",
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["Envato_Update_Checker.php"]
    }
}
```

---

In your main project:

- require the "updater" package in the `composer.json`  of your main project

  - the updater packages included the api package via it's require section (so you get both)
- add `require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');` to the project bootstrap
- enjoy Class via Composers Autoloader: `new erayalakese\Envato_Update_Checker(...);`

---

Remove this line:

https://github.com/erayalakese/envato-update-checker/blob/master/Envato_Update_Checker.php#L11

Comment: thank you so much. I didn't try it yet but I've a question. Why should I require both projects in my main project's composer.json ? Because *package B* is already require *package A*. Won't it work if I just require *package B* ?

Comment: Yes, my fault. You are correct Eray, because you already have `"require": { "erayalakese/envato-market-api": "^1.0" }` in the updater. When you require the updater in the main project, you get the API, too.