# Installed illuminate/routing But no ClassLoader

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am following the following tutorial

http://www.gufran.me/post/laravel-illuminate-router-package-in-your-application/

My composer.json looks like this

```
{
    "name": "superior/siginin",
    "description": "Sign In Example",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "A G",
            "email": "ag@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "illuminate/routing":"*",
        "illuminate/events":"*"
    }
}
```

My index.php looks like this..

```
<?php
/**
 * User: ag
 * Date: 2/27/17
 * Time: 10:08 AM
 */

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'vendor/illuminate/support/helpers.php';
$basePath = str_finish(dirname(__FILE__), '/');
$controllersDirectory = $basePath . 'Controllers';
$modelsDirectory = $basePath . 'Models';

// register the autoloader and add directories
Illuminate\Support\ClassLoader::register();
Illuminate\Support\ClassLoader::addDirectories(array($controllersDirectory, $modelsDirectory));
```

For some strange Reason `Illuminate\Support\ClassLoader` was not loaded into my page

Does anyone have a clue to why this is. The version of Illuminate\Routing it added was `v5.4.13`

according to the api. It should be in there.

Comment: did you update the classmap? Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619063/composer-classmap-autoload-does-not-load-new-files-in-folder

Comment: I understand what your saying. As far as doing the ClassLoading within the composer.json file instead. But still, It doesn't explain why when I go to https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Support/ClassLoader.html I can see the Class is clearly there but when I look into my vendor files. its not.

Comment: That worked for me but I just need to know why composer did not add a Class that should be in there

Comment: In api docs ( https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Support/ClassLoader.html ) ClassLoader is present, but not in source code ( https://github.com/illuminate/support/tree/5.4 ).