# Composer Autoload Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, autoload

I started a laravel project in version 5.5, I have been working with version 5.1.

In this version I use the folder 'nob' and I use it to develop some classes to turn them into components.

I used the following composer.json in the version 5.1:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Nob\\": "nob/"
    }
},
```

And this is the version 5.5:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Nob\\": "nob/"
    }
},
```

I get this error:
[image]

This is the class, her namespace is correct

```
<?php namespace Nob\Payeezy\Types;

use Nob\Payeezy\Payeezy;

class Authorization extends Payeezy
{
```

And this is the tree:

[image]

I use PhpStorm and he [recognizes the namespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJtpi.png)
[image]

I do not know what may be happening, I used composer dump-autoload and nothing.

Comment: Is ``config.optimize-autoloader`` in composer.json set to true? If so, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619063/composer-classmap-autoload-does-not-load-new-files-in-folder

Comment: Yes, its is set to true, i removed composer.lock file and used composer update. I'm waiting for it to end :/

Comment: Nothing, its not work :/

Comment: If nothing is working, I'd suggest evaluating why you need your core application code outside of the ``App`` namespace and not in a namespace like ``App\Classes\Nob``. Maybe it should be it's own package? If so, you can have [Composer load private packages](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs) and [see Laravel's documentation on developing packages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/packages).

Comment: The reason is that I worked so well in 5.1 and it worked perfectly, everything of nob does not belong exclusively to that application because I will use it in other projects that I do in parallel, so I do not consider it to be part of the app, but if in 5.5 is the only way that will work, so I'll have to do it like that.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is correct when I tried on my PhpStorm. But you can run the following three commands:

```
$ php artisan clear-compiled 
$ composer dump-autoload
$ php artisan optimize
```

And this will clear the current compiled files, update the classes it needs and then write them back out so you don't have to do it again.

Comment: `$ php artisan optimize` is deprecated in Laravel 5.5 (and does nothing) and will be removed in 5.6. 
https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-6-removes-artisan-optimize

Comment: Y use 
    php artisan clear-compiled
and
    composer dump-autoload

and nothing.. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this commands may can help you:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Good Luck

Comment: I have used this repeatedly and nothing :/